# How do I center the content the same as the header and footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

How can I automatically center the content which is currently has a green color border? The problem here is that it will only center if I'll put a content that has a lot of words. If it does not have a lot of words, the placement of the content will looks the picture that I posted which is more placed on the left side of the page.

How can I put the content in the center while these `p` stay at the top of the left side of the table

```
                  <p>Content1</p>
                  <p>Content2</p>
                  <p>Content3</p>
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/css-d7469k?file=/example/index.js

codes:

```
<div className="App">
        <div class="page-header">
          header here

          <Divider />
          <br />
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick="window.print()"
            style={{ background: "pink" }}
          >
            PRINT ME!
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="page-footer">
         footer here
        </div>

        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>
                {/* <!--place holder for the fixed-position header--> */}
                <div class="page-header-space" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                {/* <!--*** CONTENT GOES HERE ***--> */}

                <div class="page">
                          content here
                      </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>
                {/* <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer--> */}
                <div class="page-footer-space" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Styles go here */

.page-header,
.page-header-space {
  height: 100px;
}

.page-footer,
.page-footer-space {
  height: 50px;
}

.page-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0mm;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  page-break-after: always;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid #73ad21;
}

@page {
  margin: 20mm;
}

@media print {
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  tfoot {
    display: table-footer-group;
  }

  button {
    display: none;
  }

  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle.net please and tell us what you WANT it to look like.

Comment: @chovy I have added a codesandbox link

Comment: @SSM `text-align` did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the main `CSS` class as follows:

```
.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;      
}
```

For further details about flexbox, consult this [excellent guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: is it possible where the `p` stays on the top of the left side of the table?

Comment: `@Ravenous Red`: I don't exactly understand the question from your comment but I added a link to the guide that helped me understand the many features of CSS flexbox.